# "I got tense" or "I got tensed"?

Tags: differences, tenses, questions

Instead of using "I got tense", can I use "I got tensed"?

On a similar note, instead of using "The angrier you get, the tenser your body gets", can I use "The angier you get, the more tensed your body gets"?

Answer (score 1):

‘Tensed’ is not correct. You can, however, say ‘tensed up’ - which is an expression, eg:

‘The man tensed up when the dog barked fiercely at him’.

You can’t strictly say ‘tensed’ in the second sentence (unless there is an implied ‘up’).  You’d be better off saying ‘the angrier you get, the more tensed up your body gets’.

Comment: tenser is OK, the tenser your body gets. Also, the formal is: become tense, get tense is colloquial.